# How do I search within all assets associated with a URL in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, search

When one loads a URL in a browser, various supporting or referred assets are also loaded like stylesheets, .xml, .js, media files..etc, besides the base URL document.

How do I perform a substring search in Firefox or Chrome within this set of files? Ideally, the method can skip binary assets, so it doesn't start scanning, say, a large video file.

Third-party solutions welcome. Platform is Windows (7), if it matters.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, do the developer tools (`F12` in Chrome, `Q` in Firefox) not help?

Comment: It gives me list of all related assets loaded *if* I open it before loading the page. I don't see a way to search within these assets, only their URL. I also lose this list if I close and reopen the Dev Tools.

Comment: You can't really search for assets until they have been load (how do you know where to search?). On the source tab in Chrome you can do an advanced search. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/MoyNr.png

Comment: I meant the list in Firefox Dev Tools is *populated* only if you load it before the page. If you open it during or after, any assets loaded till then don't show up, only future network activity. Thanks for the Chrome tip. Will test it.